# Calculate shipping cost once user enters address in Paypal Node Rest SDK

Tags: javascript, node.js, paypal-rest-sdk

I have set up a shipping calculator on my website based on the country selected by the customer (e.g. 5 USD to ship to UK, 8 USD to US etc). The total cost is calculated based on this selection and is then sent to PayPal where the customer is able to complete the payment and also enter their full shipping address. How do I stop the customer changing their shipping country once they are in PayPal?

I know you can pass a full shipping address from your website, but I want to only pass the country. Is there a way to update the shipping cost once the customer enters their address in PayPal, do the calculations within PayPal (when using the SDK), or alternatively preventing the user changing the shipping country within PayPal?

Creating Payment ----->

```js
"transactions": [{

                    "item_list": {
                        "items": itemArray,
                        "shipping_address": {
                            "country_code": "US",
                            *all other details to be entered in PayPal
                          }
                    },
                    "amount": {
                        "currency": "USD",
                        "total": total,
                        "details":{
                            "subtotal":subTotal,
                            "shipping":shippingCost
                        }
                    },
                    "description": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
                }]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do like making an object property constant by doing as follows,

```js
var myObj = {};

Object.defineProperty( myObj, "CONSTANT_PROP", {
  value: "US",
  writable: false,
  enumerable: true,
  configurable: true
});

console.log("Before assigning a new value : ", myObj.CONSTANT_PROP);

// If you try to assign it a new value, it will fail,

myObj.CONSTANT_PROP = "India";

console.log("After assigning a new value : ", myObj.CONSTANT_PROP);

// It still remains the same...
```

Comment: Thanks Manish, how would I integrate this with PayPal? The issue I am having at the moment is that when using PayPal you have to pass down a full address, I don't think you can pass down just a country code as I have done in the example above.

Comment: "shipping_address": {
                            "recipient_name": "Brian Robinson",
                            "line1": "4th Floor",
                            "line2": "Unit #34",
                            "city": "San Jose",
                            "country_code": "US",
                            "postal_code": "95131",
                            "phone": "011862212345678",
                            "state": "CA"
                          }, I want to include just the country_code. However PayPal doesn't accept this. I wanted to know if this scenario is possible

Comment: Please read the guidelines of PayPal API. If they required the above fields mandatory to get a response then we can not do anything. If you want to extract some field from an object then there is a destructuring syntax for that. You may refer the following link,    http://javascript.info/destructuring-assignment#object-destructuring

Comment: Yes, so from my understanding this isn't possible. However I wanted to know if it is possible to update the shipping cost after the user enters their details on PayPal, but before the payment is actually executed to reflect the cost of shipping to the country selected in PayPal?

Comment: No. I don't think so, because what is happening whenever you hit a PayPal API with some sort of data (as provided above), it will generate a transaction id which will have its amount added to the PayPal database. Even if you change the value of cost on the client side it will still refer to the amount stored on their database. So if you hit the API, the transaction is created and it is stored. You can not alter it later on.